# C# or C++ for making a game engine (in depth)

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, game-engine

What is best C# or C++ for making a game engine. I currently am a .NET C# developer and really want to use C#. Although I know C++ does support memory management and that is why a lot of big companies go for it. That being said C# is quicker in the development process and extremely familiar to me. Before anyone suggests it, yes I've used unity. I like it but want to go the long and hard extra stretch to own 100% of my own built game.

What do I lose by not going to C++? and what kind of libraries do I use, for graphics and stuff? Is that what DirectX is for? I'm trying to wrap my head around this and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean C# is quicker in development speed right?

Comment: This question is off-topic on this website. But to answer your question: want fast games? - go C++.

Comment: How is this off topic?.. there is literally a tag for game-engine.

Comment: @MistaGoustan You do not present a specific programming problem you are facing, which is what StackOverflow is for. What you have presented is a topic of discussion that will most likely sprout controversy and it's also too broad to formulate an answer for. You'd have much better luck on some forum.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the primary problem is that this is primarily an opinion-based question.

Comment: What I hope to get out of it is an answer on the problem of understanding the workings of the two languages and libraries they have to offer for a project I hope to create. What is a better way of communicating this problem, because at its bare bones it seems like the right place to ask. (although asking this should be on a different forum lol)

Comment: Yes, but you could write an entire book on that topic (which is the other problem with this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need some opinions

Perhaps I shouldn't presume to tell you what you need, but I think you'd be much better off receiving information you need to form your own opinion. Asking for opinionated answers (notice irony here) in my opinion isn't generally desirable here.

C# and C++ are both very powerful general purpose programming languages. Either language is 100% capable of creating full fledged high performing games. With that said, there are some (mostly) *objective* differences one can point out that may effect your decision.

- Garbage Collection

Whether this is a pro or con for you is for you to decide. Some people want to save themselves work and have to spend little time taking care of memory. Obviously C# shines in this regard. C++ can have elegant and easy memory management if you know how to properly use smart pointers of course, but that's still more effort than garbage collection. If you're very concerned with having tight control over resources, then C++ might be more your thing.

- Libraries

When you want to write software without reinventing wheels (and you should) a language's libraries can be just as important as the language itself. This isn't an obvious pro for either language, as both have lots of libraries supporting games. If you have to pick a winner though, I'd say it's probably C++. The language has essentially been the vernacular of game programmers for years now, and has *a lot* of maturity in this domain. C++ can directly leverage APIs as low level as OpenGL and as high as Ogre3D. There's no guarentee that your game will actually benefit from a C++ library over a C# library though. It depends on your use case.

- Standard Libraries

Continuing on the theme of libraries, this could be a pro for C#. C and C++ are two languages that have an enormous amount of libraries available. If you only count their standard libs though, then things change. Some people don't mind, or even like this. One may also want a more expansive standard set of functionality however. C++ doesn't have a small or incapable standard lib by any means, but C#'s is definitely more feature rich.

- Platform

Unless you're going to use Mono, C# is not portable. Mono is a great option, but it does have cons (that you'll have to research yourself). C++ can't tow a line like "Build once, run anywhere", but it does all the same offer damn good portability if that's what you're going for. With an OpenGL renderer (or some higher level wrapper API like SDL/SFML) you can build for pretty much any desktop environment. If you're only worried about making games for Microsoft platforms though, then this point is probably mute.

- Virtual Machine or Native

This just like garbage collection is just a factor to consider. It'll be up to you to decide if it's right for your use or not. VM's sometimes have a stigma among game programmers it seems because of supposed performance issues. It's true, if C++ is used intelligently, it will probably be a better performing game. C#'s performance isn't anything to laugh at however. A lot of games that are written today can perform fine with a C# implementation. Is using C++ really an advantage if it means 450 FPS vs 400 FPS? Sure, there's a measurable difference, but it doesn't mean much to anyone playing your game, even if they have a 144hz monitor. Memory overhead is in a similar boat. Usually C++ isn't actually *a necessity* until you start getting into seriously heavyweight games.

- Learning

Last but not least, consider the fact that you have tools you know, and tools you don't know. You already know C#, the time you have to invest learning is probably going to be much less if you choose to pass up on C++. C++ simply has additional concepts and responsibilities compared to languages like C# and Java. Some of these things you can choose to ignore. C++ won't hold you at gunpoint and force you to use multi-inheritance, and hey, that's probably easy to pass up on. Will you pass up on destructors though? Those are pretty important. What about the STL in general? Passing up on that is probably not a great idea, no best you learn STL if you're going to use C++. If you think this is worthwhile doing, then by all means go ahead. Again though, it's just something to weigh in.

Comment: This is very detailed and really helpful. really, thank you. I think I might as well keep this up even if I lose the reputation. I'd like to reference it in the future and I'd like to think others will too.

<rant> You are right "I need some opinions" seemed to be a trigger phrase. Thanks for the appropriate way of a call out where I can edit, learn, and grow, without being discouraged to post. </rant>

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to you. Keep in mind if someone downvotes your question, it's not necessarily because they think it's a bad question. I didn't think it was, otherwise I wouldn't have given an answer probably. Stackoverflow just simply has stipulations on questions, and asking for opinionated answers doesn't fit well into those stipulations.

Comment: Fair enough friend. I did take it more personal than I should, due to the lack of explanation at first. I'm receptive to reason though, to bad answering this question is preventing me from removing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a game engine in C++ while learning C++ is a big challenge.
C# is more enjoyable than C++

Why?

1. In C++, pointers are powerful and you need to know how pointers work and how to use them
2. In C++, finding libraries is not as easy as pulling a nuget package
3. In C++, creating/refactoring header and source files is annoying
4. In C++, need to compile for every CPU architecture
5. In C++, syntax may be harder to grasp at the beginning
6. In C++, using the compiler and optimizing it is a topic on its own

But if you want your game/game engine to be fast then you should go for C++

When i see people coding for games in C++ they mainly use OpenGL but thats a common mistake since most of the non-console gamers are Windows users.
My advice is to first start creating a small game using DirectX, if you feel comfortable with it, then take the next step and create your own game engine

Comment: This was very informative. You have confirmed what my gut instinct has told me, also I see what DirectX and OpenGL really is, it's an engine, not a library. That was one of my main confusions. Thanks for the help and taking the time.

Comment: I wouldn't call OpenGL and DirectX engines.  They are just a means to access the graphics card via code.  Drawing things onto the screen is just a tiny part of what a game engine does.

Comment: `When i see people coding for games in C++ they mainly use OpenGL but thats a common mistake` OpenGL is just as good of a target as DirectX, with OpenGL boasting linux compatibility.

Comment: @MichaelB. I haven't called them engines

Comment: @user2262111 True if you want cross platform compatibility